# Random Forest explanation

Tags: random-forest, computational-statistics, decision-theory

I am having trouble understanding Random Forest, especially some terms.

What is a `node` what is `node size`? What are `predicted variables` and `split variables`? Could someone clarify or point me somewhere where this is explained?

Answer (score 1):

A forest is made out of trees, a tree is a graph and the points connected in Graphs are called nodes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)

So in a decision tree or regression tree, each check of a predictor variable is a node.
A split variable is the variable whose value decides, which branch to follow next. It is what you'd call an Independent variable in other regression techniques. Predictes variable is what the name says: The dependend variable.

Comment: Okay. So far understood. Why I wonder is how can a *variable whose value decides, which branch to follow next.* (that could be GINI i.e. i suppose?).

Comment: Sorry, could you rephrase the question, possible add a verb? "How can a variable..." do what?

Comment: Sorry. How Can a variable decide which branch to follow? that means, there are many branches, and in the end, I only follow one branch? I thought RF creates many many trees and in the end each trees casts a vote what class it could be? How can you follow a branch there?

Comment: In every single tree there are a lot of branches. You follow from the stem to the leafs of a tree by making a lot of decisions. Every time any branch in any tree is split, there is a decision. Each of these decisions is based on the value of a split variable. There is only a finite number of variables on which splits of branches can be made in the whole forest: The predictor variables.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. Its still not clear to me what predictor variables are.

Comment: It is hard to explain better without knowing about your background. Maybe you could make answering easier for me and others if you explained in what context you are explosed to random forests and at what point of your journey these words appeared.

Comment: I am working with remote sensing data where random forest is used to classify data. I identify known samples of pixels (forest, water, urban areas) and pass these areas to random forest (RF). Then the algorithm classifies the whole hyperspectral image based on my training areas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41865/discussion-between-stophface-and-bernhard).